# Remove black background on custom dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog, android-styles

I want to remove the black background on custom dialog as shown in the picture. I'm sure the black background was from the dialog, not from app's background.

[image: custom dialog with black background around it] ;

**AlertDialog code**

```
public class MyAlertDialog extends AlertDialog { 
    public MyAlertDialog(Context context) 
    {  
        super(context); 
    }  

    public MyAlertDialog(Context context, int theme) 
    { super(context, theme); }
}
```

**Activity code**

```
public void showMyDialogOK(Context context, String s, DialogInterface.OnClickListener OkListener) {        
    MyAlertDialog myDialog = new MyAlertDialog(context, R.style.MyDialog2);        
    myDialog.setTitle(null); 
    myDialog.setMessage(s);        
    myDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE ,"Ok", OkListener);
    myDialog.show();    
}
```

**Styles**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialog</item>  
        </style>    

        <style name="MyTheme2" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
            <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialog</item>    
        </style> 

        <style name="AlertDialog">        
            <item name="android:fullDark">@null</item>
            <item name="android:fullBright">@null</item>
            <item name="android:topDark">@drawable/popup_top_dark</item>
            <item name="android:topBright">@null</item>
            <item name="android:centerBright">@null</item>
            <item name="android:centerDark">@drawable/popup_center_dark</item>
            <item name="android:centerMedium">@null</item>
            <item name="android:bottomDark">@null</item>
            <item name="android:bottomBright">@null</item>
            <item name="android:bottomMedium">@drawable/popup_bottom_medium</item>
        </style>

        <style name="MyDialog2" parent="@android:Theme.Dialog">        
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>    
            <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CustomButton</item>  
        </style>    

        <style name="CustomButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">        
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_stateful</item>  
        </style>
</resources>
```

**Image resources**

popup_center_dark.9.png

[image: popup_center_dark.9.png]

popup_bottom_medium.9.png

[image: popup_bottom_medium.9.png]

popup_top_dark.9.png

[image: popup_top_dark.9.png]

Comment: you have already asked this question in past also right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497449/how-to-remove-rectangle-frame-of-the-custom-dialog

Comment: the two question not same,the question have resolve solve the before question,but bring new question.before question only want to remove the frame not the background

Comment: hi pengwang, can you please share the code for custom dialog or explain  how you changed the background an button style of dialog

Comment: Not a single answer worked for me. The answer posted here is the right solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25174316/786337

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
public MyAlertDialog(
        Context context, 
        int theme
    ) extends AlertDialog { 

    super(context, theme);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
}
```

Comment: Simpler: ````getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);````

Comment: it works on Android 5.0 +, but not work on Android 4.2

Answer (score 27):

Sonehow `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable()` didn't work for me with `AlertDialog`. I found an easier solution using **Dialog**. Here's my code -

```
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_window);
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
myDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Comment: Great! 
For me, the solutions in the other answers did not work without this flag.

Answer (score 10):

After trying dozens of other solutions for this problem, what ended up working for me is:

```
<style name="translucentDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And then setting my dialog to use this theme.

Comment: For me it was "android:colorBackground" that worked, not windowBackground

Answer (score 6):

Remove the background opacity color, you just need to set the DimAmount

```
dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(float amount);
```

> The new dim amount, from 0 for no dim to 1 for full dim.

Answer (score 5):

Use below two code lines.
Tested as well.

`getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`
`getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);`

Answer (score 1):

you can create xml layout like following and set that **layout on dialog(dialog.xml)** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/white_background_bl_aatharv">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:id="@+id/instructions_view">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="text here " />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**here is the code to set layout on alert dialog :**

```
AlertDialog alert = cndtnsbuilder.create();
alert.setView(LayoutInflater.from(
currentactivity.this).inflate(
R.layout.dialog, null));
alert.show();
```

Comment: yes, iknow these methods,but i want to use modify  system  style method.

Comment: i think my method not mistake,but  idonot know why appear a black bacgground

Answer (score 1):

Following method worked for me:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 1):

//code style in style.xml :

```
<style name="translucentDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

// in activity :set style to dialog :

```
   Dialog dialogconf = new Dialog(TreeAct.this, R.style.translucentDialog);
            dialogconf.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                   dialogconf.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change Dialog parent them.

With black backround

```
<style name="MyDialog2" parent="@android:Theme.Dialog">
```

Without black background

```
<style name="MyDialog2" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog">
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the background color, on layout, you just need to set the background to @null

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@null">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: It would be better if you could also describe what is the source of the problem and why this solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my custom dialog based on the **Alertdialog.Builder**, which had a *black background showing in the title and the body* when i use:

```
builder.setView(rootView)
  .setTitle(dialog_title)
  .setMessage(dialog_mesg)
```

solution was 
1- Use one of the pre-defines alert dialog builder's themes:

- THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK
- THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
- THEME_HOLO_DARK
- THEME_HOLO_LIGHT THEME_TRADITIONAL

THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT worked best for me

2 - set the default dialog button (positive / negative) colors to which ever color you desire like so:

```
 Button b = mAlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
 Button d = mAlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
 b.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.primary));
 d.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.primary));
```

check the below blog post for more detail and tricks to theming options:
http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/

tested on Oreo 8.1

Answer (score 0):

In KOTLIN apply this on alert dialog object

```
window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.in `bottomSheetDialogFragment`

```
    override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    // remove black outer overlay, or change opacity
    dialog?.window?.also { window ->
        window.attributes?.also { attributes ->
            attributes.dimAmount = 0.1f
            window.attributes = attributes
        }
    }
}
```