# Remove black background of popup

Tags: android, popup

How to remove black background of popups. I am using **showAtLocation method** to show the popup.
I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10795078/4153915) but no use.
I tried the following method:

```
popup.getContentView().setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25174316/3564344) will help you..

Comment: @Vijay It's of no use.

Answer (score 2):

You can set background to the root element of your popup layout. To remove the default black background from the popup setBackgroundDrawable(null)

Example:

Background for popup window layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/background_rectangle_round"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary">
...
```

In your pop up window class

```
...
  setBackgroundDrawable(null)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set a background colour in main layout-element of your layout. Transparent is not a very useful colour for a pop-up window.

So i mean set a background in the layout file of the contentView used in:
PopupWindow(View contentView, int width, int height, boolean focusable)

Comment: It worked for me but one problem. earlier I was creating popup lik this popup = new PopupWindow(ChallengerActivity.this);  at that point in time popup was closing when I click outside the popup but now It is not closing. I tried many solutions but no result.