# alertDialog background transparent

Tags: android

When I call an **progressDialog** the whole window (background behind the progressDialog) is getting dark/grey.

I tried:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

But this changes the background of the **progressDialog** it self.
Is it possible to disable the dark/grey background behind the **progressDialog**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174165/transparent-alertdialog-has-black-background

Comment: @Adnan this changes the background of the alertDialog it self

Comment: This is standard system behavior, why would you want to change it?

Comment: because I am refreshing a live-image and the black/grey background disturbs the viewing of the image. showing the progressDialog without the full-window-background would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this solution:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialog with transparent overlay 
`style.xml:`

```
 <style name="TransparentDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Set this style in `Dialog` constructor: `R.style.TransparentDialog`

Comment: thank you! I updated my question. I changed alertDialog to progressDialog. When I use your answer, also the background of the progressDialog box gets transparent.