# Android round shape corners not round

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to use a rounded shape in several layouts, but from some reason even though the corners are rounded, in the background there are corners that are not rounded.
Does anybody have an idea why?

Code:

dialog_background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/jobim_white" ></solid>

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary" ></stroke>

<corners android:radius="8dp"></corners>

</shape>
```

search_edittext_shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp" >

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

RelativeLayout (of the dialog):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/dialog_background" >
```

LinearLayout (of the EditText):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#ECECEC">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchTypeEdtTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:drawableTint="#D0D0D0"
        android:background="@drawable/search_edittext_shape"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:textColorHint="#ECECEC"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Looks like this:

[Dialog image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z4jK.png)

[EditText image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1xue.png)

Thank you

Comment: My bad... it was there just got lost in formatting

Comment: dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

Comment: try angrytools.com

Comment: @henengel Updated my post and run it at my side. It's working fine for me so try it now. It will also work for you.

Comment: @henengel have you tried my updated solution?

Answer (score 4):

In extra corners are coming because of dialog. Your layout works perfectly in case of activities and fragments. For dialogs just set

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

or if you found any other way to set dialog background as transparent use that one.

Comment: This did work with the dialog.
I'm also using the shape on an EditText and have the same problem.
Since I'm using setBackgroundDrawable to the shape, I can't use this to set the background transparency.
Any idea?

Comment: in edittext image for which edit text you are getting like that?

Comment: @henengel have you tried my updated post for edit text?

Comment: @DeepakSachdeva Yes I tried it now and it didn't work. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ADADAD" />

    </shape>
```

Comment: I need a rounded rectangle, not oval

Comment: @ManikandanK Checked it. Except for the stroke color being different lt look the same, with the problem.

Comment: @ManikandanK I did that and it did work but generally, I still have the problem.
I'm also using the shape on an EditText and have the same problem. Since I'm using setBackgroundDrawable to the shape, I can't use this to set the background transparency. Any idea? –

Answer (score 0):

I have modified some of your code. try that
I have just added shape tag in your code. It will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="@color/jobim_white" ></solid>

       <stroke
           android:width="1dp"
           android:color="@color/colorPrimary" ></stroke>

       <corners android:radius="8dp"></corners>
    </shape>
```

for edit text use
rounded_corner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle">

      <!-- view background color -->
      <solid
          android:color="@color/colorPrimary" >
      </solid>

        <!-- If you want to add some padding -->
     <padding
          android:left="4dp"
          android:top="4dp"
          android:right="4dp"
          android:bottom="4dp"    >
     </padding>

        <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
     <corners
         android:radius="20dp"   >
     </corners>
</shape>
```

And in your LinearLayout

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#ECECEC">

            <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/searchTypeEdtTxt"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_search"
                 android:drawableTint="#D0D0D0"
                 android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                 android:hint="@string/search"
                 android:textColorHint="#ECECEC"
                 android:textCursorDrawable="@color/black" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @henengel add dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)).

Comment: Did it and indeed it fixed the dialog issue. Still have the edittext problem

Comment: @henengel I have changed my post according to your requirement for EditText. try this.
You can also try your edit text style here.

Comment: Tried it didn't work. The not round corners are even more visible.

Comment: @henengel I have updated my post again and run it at my side. It's working fine so try it now. It will also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your background and it's drawable. The problem here is the dialog theme.

Try to set dialog background to transparent, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25174316/6507689).

If this won't help try changing the theme to custom one, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18886282/6507689)

Comment: This maybe fixes the dialog problem, but not the EditText one.

dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)) 

also fixed the dialog problem.