# How to have transparent viewGroup while creating a dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, viewgroup

I'm creating an Android app and inflating a view inside onCreateView(..) for a DialogFragment. Result is this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApZ5k.jpg

I want the dialog to become translucent too (like the background). Here's my dialog layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/fadedBlack">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/confirm"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.952"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/task_name"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/deadline"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.346" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/task_deadline"
    android:layout_width="97dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/task_name"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.571"
    tools:text="7:30 AM Mon"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/task_name"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/name"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.LightEditText"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/change_deadline"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_schedule"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/task_name"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/task_deadline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/task_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.974" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/build_image"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_build"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/confirm"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/task_name"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Things I tried:

a) Setting fadedBlack's value to a transparent color. The result was that the dark black color was converted to plain white.

b) I read somewhere that the background color is black with 60% alpha, so I tried setting fadedBlack's value to that, but in vain.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25174316/6025006). I was building the dialog with AlertDialog.Builder() which doesn't do very well with transparent dialogs. So one has to manually instantiate a  dialog and assign the view to it.

Comment: Try background color code #80000000

Comment: post your complete layout for dialog

Comment: @tompadre Done!

Comment: @DeewankshiSharma It's closer, but not quite. I think the inner dialog puts a solid white color and the backgroundDrawable is simply an overlay over that. I updated the screenshot, take a look.

Comment: Try the same with popupwindow, background color #80000000 works exactly like a overlay.