# Hide the background of parent layout

Tags: android, android-cardview

[image: Screen shot]

This is an alert dialog. I don't want to show the grey coloured portion (at top), which is background of the parent layout; instead that portion should be clear and the previous activity should be shown there as being shown outside the dialog. Also the border of the circular image view be  tight with the image. How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Mylayout.xml

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#727272">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/card_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_save"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView_DoB"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/dd_mm_yyyy"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_date"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ib_DoB_in_dialog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/til_date"
                android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/calendar"
                android:contentDescription="@string/calendar_image" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_DoB_weekday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/til_date"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/til_date"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/name"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_category"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/til_name"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/sp_category"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/Category">
                </Spinner>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>




            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_mobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/til_category"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_mobile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/mobile_number_optional"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="13"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/til_mobile"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <TableRow>
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_discard"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/discard" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_save_data"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/save" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/civ_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_person_image"
        card_view:civ_border_width="2dp"
        card_view:civ_border_color="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use Fragments and swap between them.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Read the docs, fragments is well covered there

Answer (score 0):

add this on your parent xml

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

and add this to your code so the whole alert dialog become transparent

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0);
```

Comment: Yes, but then the whole dialog background becomes white and I don't want that. I want the half portion of the image be above the white portion as now except the grey portion.

Comment: i updated my answer , your alert dialog default color is white

Comment: the problem is with your alert dialog that is not transparent
see here for more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174165/transparent-alertdialog-has-black-background

Comment: Thanks @Boukharist. alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); did the trick. Now can you please tell me how to make the border of circular image view tight to the image.

Comment: Also a warning is shown-"Method invocation 'setBackgroundDrawable' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'." How to fix the warning?