# how to programatically theme an activity to be like a dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-dialog

## Question

How does one programatically (without touching the `AndroidManifext.xml`) set the theme of an `Activity` [so that it looks like a dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TA2C.png)?

Note: I am ok with modifying the `AndroidManifext.xml` as long as it does not need to be modified in order to switch between making it look like a normal activity or a dialog.

## What I've tried so far

I tried the following as per [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22216966/2898715):

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
        Log.d(TAG,"Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: "+Build.VERSION.SDK_INT); // 23
    }
}
```

But it ends up [blacking out everything in the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh5Kd.png).

I also saw [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119116/2898715), and tried:

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }
}
```

but it ends up making [everything black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLEWV.jpg).

What do? Thank you.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog. May be you can also interested in this: https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung thank you. I saw that post too, but most of those answers involve modifying the `AndroidManifest.xml` which I don't want to do. I tried the first method mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22216966/2898715, but it didn't produce satisfactory results as mentioned in my question. Also, thank you for the github link, I checked it out, however I really hope there is a simpler solution.

Comment: @Eric has amazingly solved this problem, THANKS, sent a bounty. Must set Theme.AppCompat.Dialog in manifest. You may only set your own style in onCreate. It was also the answer to my question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67045156/294884

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Background

The `Activity` behind an `Acivity` is drawn if the foreground activity's theme according to its `AndroidManifest.xml` is a dialog; otherwise the android os will **not** draw the `Activity` behind it (probably to save memory since it usually won't be seen anyway).

To exploit this, we set the theme of our `Acitvity` to a dialog in the manifest, making the android os draw the `Activity` behind it, but later, programatically set our `Activity`'s theme to whatever we like at runtime.

## [Example on github](https://github.com/ericytsang/stackoverflow.35834481/tree/master)

[I made an example and put it on github.](https://github.com/ericytsang/stackoverflow.35834481/tree/master)

## Tutorial

**Step 1:** create two custom themes for your application in `styles.xml`. One for normal activities, and another for dialog activities. It is important for the custom dialog theme to inherit from a base theme that is also a dialog. In my case, the parent theme is `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize`). Here is my `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- custom normal activity theme -->    
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>

    <!-- custom dialog activity theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize">
        <!-- removing the dialog's action bar -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Step 2:** in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, set the theme of the `Activity` in question to any dialog theme. This makes the android os think that the `Activity` is a dialog, so it will draw the `Activity` behind it, and not black it out. In my case, I used `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog`. Below is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.eric.questiondialog_artifact">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".DialogActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"> <-- IMPORTANT!!! -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Step 3:** in the actual activity, set the theme programatically to either the theme for normal activities, or the theme for dialogs. My `DialogActivity.java` is below:

```
package com.example.eric.questiondialog_artifact;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class DialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Dialog); // can either use R.style.AppTheme_Dialog or R.style.AppTheme as deined in styles.xml
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check this solution with application target API 27 and above. I got crash with fullscreen theme `Only fullscreen activities can request orientation`. When i set fullscreen is default and change to dialog theme at runtime. The background is black. If dialog theme is preset, the fullscreen is crash

Comment: I just tested this solution on Android Pie (API 28). It seems to work fine without crashing when programmatically starting the Activity as a fullscreen one or dialog one.

Comment: can you add a sample project on github? Thank you

Comment: @NamTrung hey, I finally got around to creating [an example for this answer](https://github.com/ericytsang/stackoverflow.35834481/tree/master).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your sample

Comment: I forgot to mention that my activity have forced orientation to lanscape. If i add `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` to `NextActivity`, the app will crash

Comment: I will see if i can create a branch on the repo that has a working solution for this case. I'm not sure if it is possible to do this.

Comment: how can I setOnDismissListener on activity opened as Dialog?

Comment: @RiddhiShah if the dialog is actually an `Activity`, you can either put some code in the `Activity`'s [`onDestroy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy()) lifecycle method. Or, you can use the `startActivityForResult` when launching the `Activity` so that you can handle the result in `onActivityResult` (see [Getting a result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result))

Comment: @Eric I am opening my dialog activity whenever I receive a push notification. so I won't be able to startActivityForResult. I gave theme in AndroidManifest like above.

Comment: Hey @RiddhiShah , sorry for the late reply. maybe you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52788197/2898715 ? and if you want the `onDismissListener` code to only be run when the activity was started from the notification (and not run it if the activity was started from elsewhere) then you can pass in a special flag/parameter into the activity (via the intent you use to start it), and check that flag when checking `isFinishing`, too

Comment: For anyone who wants to change the size of the activity, he must delete .FixedSize in the `style` and change the params of the `LinearLayout`

Comment: Notice .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67041191/updated-to-4-2rc1-and-transparent-activities-do-not-work-suddenly-black

Answer (score 2):

if what you're looking for is just a theme with transparent background for you activity, just use this:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

apply this style to your activity in your AndroidManifest file and this is it

Answer (score 0):

I am late but still for future users
you need to call the below code after `setTheme()` Calling this allows the Activity behind this one to be seen again. Once all such Activities have been redrawn

```
// setTheme()
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            try {
            Method getActivityOptions = Activity.class.getDeclaredMethod("getActivityOptions");
            getActivityOptions.setAccessible(true);
            Object options = getActivityOptions.invoke(activity);

            Class<?>[] classes = Activity.class.getDeclaredClasses();
            Class<?> translucentConversionListenerClazz = null;
            for (Class clazz : classes) {
                if (clazz.getSimpleName().contains("TranslucentConversionListener")) {
                    translucentConversionListenerClazz = clazz;
                }
            }
            Method convertToTranslucent = Activity.class.getDeclaredMethod("convertToTranslucent",
                    translucentConversionListenerClazz, ActivityOptions.class);
            convertToTranslucent.setAccessible(true);
            convertToTranslucent.invoke(activity, null, options);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }
        } else {
            try {
            Class<?>[] classes = Activity.class.getDeclaredClasses();
            Class<?> translucentConversionListenerClazz = null;
            for (Class clazz : classes) {
                if (clazz.getSimpleName().contains("TranslucentConversionListener")) {
                    translucentConversionListenerClazz = clazz;
                }
            }
            Method method = Activity.class.getDeclaredMethod("convertToTranslucent",
                    translucentConversionListenerClazz);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(activity, new Object[] {
                null
            });
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try these code before `dailog.setMessage(...);`

```
Dialog id  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);

Dialog ID = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);

//Default theme
```

> Try this for Old theme 
>      `Dialog ID = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL);`

Try these for KITKAT theme

```
Dialog ID = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK); //Dark


Dialog ID = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

> Try these codes for Pragmatically

`Exmaple`

```
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
            dialog.setTitle("HAI");
            dialog.setMessage("look");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is exmaple theme", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```